# Duplicate sheets shouldn't be added

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I would like to write a vba code that will not allow to add duplicate sheets with same name. I have a code that is assigned to button on the sheet that is used to change the name of the active sheet.

Sheets are copied from "Main" sheet and hence all the sheets will have button to rename the sheet based on the value selected in the cells A8 and K11 (Both these cells have drop down list with values).

My concern is when user selects the button to rename the sheet, it should look for all the sheets in workbook and display a message if duplicate sheet exists else it should rename the sheet. I am confused in passing values, I am still a starter. Please help

```
Sub RenameCurrentSheet()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
    For x = 1 To worksh
       If ActiveSheet.Name = "MainSheet" Then
       MsgBox "You Cannot Change Name of This Sheet!!!"
       Exit For
    Else
      ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A8").Value & "-" & Range("K11").Value
      Exit For
     End If
   Next x
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the worksheets use code like this:

```
    dim wks as Worksheet
    for I = 1 to Application.Worksheets.Count
        set wks = Application.Worksheets(i)
        Debug.Print wks.Name
        .... whatever else you want do do
    next i    

    set wks = Nothing    '  When done with the object
```

Comment: I used the if condition which i mentioned above in your code and that dint help!! I feel something wrong in my code logically speaking which I am not able to figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

Just try and reference the worksheet to see if it exists - if it throws an error, then the sheet doesn't exist.

Your code fails as you're always looking at the activesheet, but never changing which sheet is active.

```
Public Sub CopyAndRenameSheet()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim sNewName As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Copy the template to the end of the workbook.
        .Worksheets("MainSheet").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

        'Set reference to last sheet in workbook (the one you've just copied).
        Set wrkSht = .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count)

        With wrkSht
            'Get the new name from the ranges.
            sNewName = .Range("A8") & "-" & .Range("K11")

            If WorkSheetExists(sNewName) Then
                MsgBox "You Cannot Change Name of This Sheet!!!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical

                'Do something with the sheet, otherwise you'll be left with a
                'sheet called something like "MainSheet (1)".
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wrkSht.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            Else
                .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
                wrkSht.Name = sNewName
                .Protect Password:="xyz"
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: I dont have constant sheet name to use it your code. Please help me in understanding if I have mistaken. Sheet names are based on the values on the cells provided above value1-value2. Hence it has to take the values from these two cells and check if workbook has same name. so I m confused on how to give sheet name/somehseet name in your code.

Comment: ok, so your `MainSheet` is a template sheet.  This sheet is copied and renamed using the values in cell `A8` and `K11`.  Are the values in `A8` and `K11` dates?

Answer (score 0):

This code copies the name to be assigned from the template instead of the ActiveSheet. If you create the name from the active sheet and make sure that the name meets Excel requirements for sheet names, this code ought to work.